# how to disable only intellisense of system files(msvc,windows kits) in visual studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, intellisense

Visual studio Intellisense shows too many variables and functions. I found that most of functions are related to header in msvc/include or windows kits/include.

If you create an empty project and press 'a' in the main function, you can see the following picture.

[press 'a' in main()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qq9KT.png)

I did not declare #include anything, but intellisense shows system functions and variables due to automatically included system header files.

I want to use intellisense only for the headers or namespace I declared. I don't want to use that for system header files.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid the answer is negative.

For now C++ Intellisense option doesn't support this behavior.

What you create seems to be a windows desktop app. In this way,windows content from `#include <windows.h>` is available when you use C++ Intellisense.

For a windows desktop app, the `#include <windows.h>` is necessary, and for C++ Intellisense, it won't recognize if some variables or functions come from windows.h. It will display all variables from the header files included in the .cpp file.(Both #include declared by you and `#include windows.h` declared in the framework)

In addition:Maybe you can go help menu=>send feedback=>provide a suggestion to post your idea for this.